# R Simmer - lapply on simulation environments built with a loop resulting in identical simulations

Tags: r

I have created the following MWE to illustrate the code. Consider a system with 20 queues and servers (such that for each server there is a FCFS queue). When an arrival comes, it takes the shortest. Say you wish to compare 20 simulations, each 400 over units of time from start to finish.

You can see in my code that the queues are added using a for loop (indeed, this becomes necessary when simulating asymptotically large queueing systems).

```r
library(simmer)
library(simmer.plot)

set.seed(1337)
sim<-simmer()

queues<- vector(length=10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  queues[i]<- paste0("q_",i)
}


queueing_system <- trajectory() %>%
  select(function()queues,policy = "shortest-queue")%>%
  seize_selected(1)%>%
           timeout(function() rpois(1, 10)+1)%>%
  release_selected()

for(i in 1:10){sim%>%
    add_resource(queues[i], 1)}
sim%>%
  add_generator("path",queueing_system, function()rexp(1,20))


environments<-lapply(1:20, function(o){
  sim%>%run(400)
})

queue1<-list()
for(a in 1:20){
  exqueue<-get_mon_resources(environments[a])[which(get_mon_resources(environments[a])[1]=="q_1"),]
  exqueue$total<-exqueue[,3]+exqueue[,4]
  queue1[[a]] <- exqueue
}

head(queue1[[1]])
head(queue1[[2]]) #both are the same!
```

Draw notice to the following two lines in particular - I pull out the total amount of people in the queue #1 after a discrete event has occured:

```r
head(queue1[[1]])
head(queue1[[2]]) #both are the same!
```

Indeed, they are the same between all sims (not just 1 and 2). Is there a way to generate unique sample paths for each instance?

Comment: You can probably get some answers using the mailing list of that R package: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/simmer-devel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulation environment, as every environment in R, has [reference semantics](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#explicit-envs). Therefore, here

```r
environments<-lapply(1:20, function(o){
  sim%>%run(400)
})
```

when `o=1`, the simulation runs. And then, when `o=2...20`, you are calling the same simulation environment, which already is at `t=400`, so you are running nothing. But even if you reset the simulation:

```r
environments<-lapply(1:20, function(o){
  sim %>% reset() %>% run(400)
})
```

This effectively runs 20 different simulations, but you obtain a list of 20 references to the last simulation (again, due to reference semantics).

How to solve this? Simply instantiate a new simulation environment for each replication; i.e., put your call to `simmer()` inside the replication function, [as the introduction vignette does](https://r-simmer.org/articles/simmer-01-introduction.html#replication).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for your help!